# Beautiful Soup filtering for more than one keyword

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**CODE**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(link['href']).read(), 'lxml')
    # Find CompanyA links
    for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True, text='CompanyA'):
        print (link['href'])
```

Is it possible to filter for more than one, like this?

```
text='CompanyA' OR text='CompanyB' OR text='CompanyC'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you all the elements which have a text attribute and match your list of texts.

```
soup.findAll('a', href=True, text=lambda value: value and value in ["CompanyA", "CompanyB", "CompanyC"])
```

Comment: This would also match 'CompanyD', try `value and value in ["CompanyA", "CompanyB", "CompanyC"]`

Comment: You are right, psilocybin. Updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression.

```
import re
for link in soup.findAll("a", href=True,text=re.compile("CompanyA|CompanyB|CompanyC")):
        print (link['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is a neat way to accomplish the same task.